# Not able to find routes in Koa2, facing error TypeError: route.routes is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, koa2

I am working on Node Koa2 API. I am performing CRUD operations with **Mongoose**. When I am working with only one file ("app.js") its working fine. But when I am separating it into controllers, routes and model, it is showing following error: **TypeError: route.routes is not a function** in the app.js file. Thanks in Advance for the help.

Error Description:

[image]

```
import Koa from 'koa';
const BodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const logger = require('koa-logger');

import router from './routes/index';


require('mongoose');
require('./config.js');

const app = new Koa();

// Use the bodyparser middlware
app.use(BodyParser());
app.use(logger());


app
.use(router.routes())
.use(router.allowedMethods());


app.listen(3001, () =>{
console.log('Server is running on port: 3001');
})
export default app;
```

Comment: In order to help, I'd really like to see what `/routes/index.js` looks like.  Otherwise, it is not possible to know why the error is occurring.

Comment: Hi @DavinTryon  I have included the code screenshots in this comment.
routes/index.js: https://i.imgur.com/yVjLLV5.png and 
routes/cities.js: https://i.imgur.com/gVdsN87.png
thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for reply, But actually I have attached  Error Description image in Que. description of error that I am facing. So please refer it.

Answer (score 0):

wellcome to SO, change the fallowing in your code:

```
app.use(router.routes()) //replace for
app.use('/', router)
```

Hope it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per your issue for e.g. your index file path is (./routes/index).Then the code in app.js as follows:-

```
 var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/',index);
```